# php random array - random again when doing while

Tags: php, arrays, random, shuffle

Right now, every single time I do a while do, it goes from top to bottom of my array. How can I make it go through each value but in a random mode, not from top to bottom?

Here's what I have:

```
$xbb = array('avotf1',
'avotf2',
'avotf3',
'avotf4',
'avotf5',
'avotf6',
'avotf7',
'avotf8',
'avotf9',
'avotf11',
'avotf12',
'avotf13',
'avotf14',
'avotf15',
'avotf10');

foreach($xbb as $item)
{

echo "$item<br>";

}
```

How do I shuffle the random array that I have and still show all 15 values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shuffle it with [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php):

```
shuffle($xbb);
```

Searching Google for **php shuffle array** will give you tons of results as well, by the way.